# rails: exclude blank select_tag from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, scope

I have a form on index.html.erb (User views):

```
<%= form_tag( '', :method => :get ) do %>

<% @company = Position.all.map { |p| [ p.company, p.company ] } %>
<%= select_tag "company", options_for_select((@company), params[:position_id]), { :include_blank => true, :reject_if => @company.blank? } %> 

<% @industry = Position.all.map { |p| [ p.industry, p.industry ] } %>
<%= select_tag "industry", options_for_select((@industry), params[:position_id]), { :include_blank => true, :reject_if => @industry.blank? } %> 

<%= submit_tag 'Filter', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

and a controller (User controller):

```
def index
    if params[:company] && params[:industry]
      @users = User.companies(params[:company]).industries(params[:industry])
    elsif params[:company]
      @users = User.companies(params[:company])
    elsif params[:industry]
      @users = User.companies(params[:industry])
    else 
      @users = User.all
    end
end
```

A User has many companies and industries through positions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :position_ids

  has_many :positions
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :industries, :through => :positions
  has_one :current_position, :class_name => "Position", :conditions => { :is_current => true }

  scope :companies, lambda { |*company| {:include => :positions, :conditions => ["positions.company = ?", company]} }
  scope :industries, lambda { |*industry| {:include => :positions, :conditions => ["positions.industry = ?", industry]} }
end
```

Despite the if statement in my user controller, I cannot get my view to ignore blank entries in either the company or industry field. For instance, a blank company and "Internet" industry filter returns this url:

...users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&company=&industry=Internet&commit=Filter

how do I modify my code to ignore a blank company field so that the url excludes 'company=&' entirely? In this case, I get the returned results that I want:

...users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&industry=Internet&commit=Filter

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is check to see if the parameters are blank.

```
if !params[:company].blank? && !params[:industry].blank?
  @users = User.companies(params[:company]).industries(params[:industry])
elsif !params[:company].blank? && params[:industry].blank?
    @users = User.companies(params[:company])
elsif !params[:industry].blank? && params[:company].blank?
    @users = User.companies(params[:industry])
else
    @users = User.all
end
```

When you submit the form, the variables are being set. Just that, they have blank values. So you need to check if they are blank instead of whether they exist.